# Pagination not working in wp Blog

Tags: php, html, wordpress

```
    <?php 
        $args=array(
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'cat' => '',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'paged'=>$paged
        );
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();  ?>

    <div id="box1">

    <h1 class="blog1"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <h2 class="blog2">Posted By :- <?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?> <span class="blog3">
        <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span></h2>
        <?php $a=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>  
        <span class="blog4"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $a; ?>&w=200&h=150&q=100" alt=""></span>
        <p class="blogcontent"><?php $a=get_the_content();
            $b=strlen($a);
            if($b>770)
                {
                    $con = substr($a, 0, strrpos(substr($a,0,770),' ')).  '....';
                    echo $con;          
                ?>
                <p style=" float:right;"><a style ="margin-top:15px;" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?> ">Read More</a></p>
        <?php
                }
                else
                {
                    echo $a;                
                }           
            ?>
            </p>
    </div>

<?php //endforeach; 
 endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<span style="padding:30px;"><?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {wp_paginate();} 
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
</span>
```

I working on `wordpress` blog and make a pagination in blog there were issue in pagination.when click on page 2 the url change but page not changed.i am using the following code for that
    Thanks & Regards

Comment: Did you first define `$paged` as `$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`?

Comment: yes, i have already defined it's
<?php if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {$paged = get_query_var('page'); } else {$paged = 1; }

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php 
        $args=array(
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'cat' => '',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'paged'=>$paged
        );
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();  ?>

    <div id="box1">

    <h1 class="blog1"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <h2 class="blog2">Posted By :- <?php the_author_meta('display_name'); ?> <span class="blog3">
        <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span></h2>
        <?php $a=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>  
        <span class="blog4"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $a; ?>&w=200&h=150&q=100" alt=""></span>
        <p class="blogcontent"><?php $a=get_the_content();
            $b=strlen($a);
            if($b>770)
                {
                    $con = substr($a, 0, strrpos(substr($a,0,770),' ')).  '....';
                    echo $con;          
                ?>
                <p style=" float:right;"><a style ="margin-top:15px;" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?> ">Read More</a></p>
        <?php
                }
                else
                {
                    echo $a;                
                }           
            ?>
            </p>
    </div>

<?php //endforeach; 
 endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<span style="padding:30px;">

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
</span>
```

Alternatively, you can see [this](http://www.wpexplorer.com/pagination-wordpress-theme/) tutorial if you want to have numbered pagunation.

Comment: try adding `$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $temp;
wp_reset_query();` before `<span style="padding:30px;"><?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {wp_paginate();} `